# matrix regression under side conditions

Tags: matrices, linear-regression

I want to solve the folowing problem **B*M=V**, where **B** is the unknown of size *3x3*, **M** of size *3xN* and **V** of size *3xN*. The difficulty is, that **B** has to be unitary.

*N* is in the range of 500. All matrices are real.

Solving the problem by multiplying from right with the pseudoinverse of **M** gives a solution that is close to being unitary.

Does somebody have a hint how to solve it? Best would be a solution by aid of Matlab or a C++ library like Eigen.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, the singular value decompositions of $V$ and $M$ can be written in the form
$$ V = U_1 \Sigma U_2^*, \ M = U_3 \Sigma U_2^*$$
with the same $\Sigma$ and $U_2$, and you have $B = U_1 U_3^*$.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! It's a really elegant solution! But I still have some questions =)
Since for me, the equality sign in $BM=V$ does not hold (but the error has to be minimized), I have $$V = U_1 \Sigma_1 U_2^*, 
M = U_3\Sigma_2 U_4^* $$
I have reordered $\Sigma_2$ and $U_4^*$ in a way that they are closest to $\Sigma_1$ and $U_2^*$. Of course $U_3$ was reordered accordingly to that.
Now the question is: Is the resulting $B$ the best possible unitary solution to $BM=V$ or is it just one close solution? And if so: why?